# Child class inherit Parent class self.variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

I am not sure if this questions has been asked as I can't see any similar issues.

Below are my issues:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.name = kwargs.get('name',None)
        self.age = kwargs.get('age',None)
        self.year = '1995'
        print(self.name,self.age,self.year)

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.parent_name = self.name
        self.parent_age = self.age
        self.parent_year = self.year
        print("Parent Details: ",self.parent_name,self.parent_age,self.parent_year)

>>> res = Parent(name='Derek',age=22)
Derek 22 1994
>>> res2 = Child()
None None 1994
```

My question is, why does the child class return None? I have already used super() to inherit the parent init class. Below is my expectation and how can I achieve that?

```
>>> res = Parent(name='Derek',age=22)
Derek 22 1994
>>> res2 = Child()
Parent Details: Derek 22 1994
```

Comment: Your expectation is weird/bad.  `Child()` was created without any name and age, why should it re-use data from some otherwise unrelated instance?

Comment: You didn't pass a name or age when creating an instance of `Child`, so naturally that instance does not have a name or age.

Comment: You need to pass the same arguments to Child as you do for Parent.

Comment: Suppose you have two objects `p1 = Parent(name="Derek", age=22)` and `p2 = Parent(name="Donna", age=21)`. Which values would you expect `Child()` to inherit? Inheritance applies to name lookups within the *class* hierarchy, not relationships between individual *instances* of those classes.

Comment: @chepner, how can my child inherit the parent's value then? I have updated the code. I need to do something like this.

Comment: @wim, i have updated the code, i need to use it in such way

Comment: You should avoid using `**kwargs` for now. It seems to obscure your understanding of what is going on.

Comment: @mkrieger1, how can I get the parent's value on the child class then? my parent class are called in the first place, then trigger the child class. So parent class variable with assigned value needs to be shared with child class

Comment: It can't; you have to *tell* `Child` which parent to use. `res2 = Child(res)`, with `Child.__init__` updated appropriately. Inheritance means that if `Parent` defines a method like `def eat(self, food)`, then `res2.eat("apple")` inherits the definition of the `eat` method, not that any particular `Parent` instance is involved in the eating process.

Comment: I can't tell for sure, but it seems to me like you are confusing classes and instances of classes. which are very different things.

Comment: @chepner, why is the self.year value show up at Child class then?

Comment: @martineau, I don't understand why self.name and self.age returns None in Child class while self.year shows 1994 in child class while both are initialized in init parent class

Comment: @DerekLee Because you called the parent class's `__init__` method to set `self.name`, `self.age`, and `self.year`. As I noted in my answer, this is a weird hierarchy that doesn't really model real-word child/parent relationships.

Comment: Classes for the most part don't contain data, they consist mainly of code and methods (functions) so they're more like code templates than anything else. Thus it's fairly meaningless to say a class inherits data from another class (whether that other class is a parent class or not). See the Wikipedia article on [Object-Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

Comment: @martineau.. thanks for your advice. I got it finally :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inheritance, roughly speaking, deals with class-level concepts. Consider this parent class:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.year = '1995'

    def eat(self, food):
        print("I ate {}".format(food))
```

Now consider this child class:

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, name, age, p):
        super().__init__(name, age)
        self.parent_name = p.name
        self.parent_age = p.age
        self.parent_year = p.year
        # Or, since you can already access the name, age, and year of
        # an instance of Parent, just save the instance directly:
        self.parent = p
```

Then you could write

```
p = Parent("Derek", 22)
c = Child("Didi", 9, p)
```

Now `c.parent_name == "Derek"` and `c.parent_age == 22`, but `c.name == "Didi"` and `c.age == 9`. You explicitly *told* `Child` who the parent of Didi was; inheritance is not involved. (Inheritance *is* involved in setting the `name` and `age` attributes, since you call `super().__init__`, but this is kind of a weird class hierarchy. `Child` is a child class of `Parent`, but that doesn't really model the real world very well: not all children are parents.)

Where inheritance comes in is with the `eat` method. There is no `Child.eat` method, so when you call `c.eat("apple")`, what happens is `Parent.eat` gets called with a `Child` instance as its first argument.

```
>>> p.eat("apple")
"I ate apple"
>>> c.eat("apple")
"I ate apple"
```

---

Inheritance should be used to model "is-a" relationships; if `B` inherits from `A`, then for all intents and purposes an instance of `B` should be usable anywhere an instance of `A` is usable. Your use here violates that; a `Child` *has* a parent, but is not necessarily a parent itself, and so `Child` should not inherit from `Parent`. A more sane modeling would involve just one class:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age, parents=None):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.parents = parents

# We've lost the genealogical records, and don't know who
# Bob and Alice's parents were.
first_man = Person("Alice", 25)
first_woman = Person("Bob", 25)
children = [
    Person("Charlie", 15, [first_man, first_woman]),
    Person("Derek", 13, [first_man, first_woman])
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think the main point of your answer here is to pass the parent class to child class.

c = Child("Didi", 9, p)

Comment: I still got to stick with **kwargs since my organization is using it. However, what I do is as below:

`c = Child(parent_class = p)` and then process it with `p = kwargs.get(parent_class,None)` and then go with `self.parent_name = p.name`

Comment: `parent`, not `parent_class`. `p` is an *instance* of `Parent`, not the class itself. Seriously, make sure someone at your organization does code review on whatever you are writing, because you don't seem to have a firm enough grasp of the basics to be writing anything on your own.

Comment: opps..got it. Yea, there's a senior..but he's away for now. So seeking help on here